# All quarters in current year in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I want to display the quarters in the current year like -

```
2022 Q 1    
2022 Q 2
2022 Q 3
2022 Q 4
```

Is there any way to do this ?
When I am using the below query, I am only getting current quarter -

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy" Q "q') as QuaterDate from dual
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query such as

```sql
 SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyy" Q "')||level AS QuaterDate 
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 4
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy" Q "') || xmlcast(column_value as number) as qtr
from   xmltable('1 to 4')
;

QTR     
--------
2022 Q 1
2022 Q 2
2022 Q 3
2022 Q 4
```